# regular expression matching any non white space char string ending with "&s"

Tags: regex

Regular expression matching any non white space char string ending with "&s"

Tried RE:

\S*&s

The issue is \S includes all the chars including "&s". In my string when "&s" occurs RE should end over there but it is not.

Example : 
String:
**abcd$%+abv&sabc**
String extracted by RE:  **abcd$%+abv&s**

Comment: What is expected output for a string like `123&s678&s`? Two matches, `123&s` and `678&s`, or no match?

Comment: Looks like you just need `\S*?&s`